# Debugging SIGSEGV with no_std, no_main program running on x86_64 Linux

Tags: linux, rust, rust-embedded

I have a simple program which is no_std and no_main. I want to run it on x86_64 with Linux.
I have set panic = abort in Cargo.toml and provide following custom panic handler.

```
    #[panic_handler]
    #[no_mangle]
    fn panic_fault(panic_info: &PanicInfo) -> ! {
        let msg = rust_alloc::format!("{}", panic_info);
        unsafe {
            libc::write(1, msg.as_ptr() as *const libc::c_void, msg.len()); 
            libc::exit(255);
        }
        unreachable!();
    }
```

However it gets `SIGSEGV` on line  `let msg = rust_alloc::format!("{}", panic_info);`

I checked that my custom allocator returns pointer of address `0x5555555710b0` for msg.
with proc/[pid]/maps I check that the above address in heap
`555555571000-555555572000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]`

in /var/log/syslog I can see following line
`traps: fibonacci[1768947] general protection fault ip:5619f0d118a3 sp:7fff038b97a8 error:0 in fibonacci[5619f0d11000+13000]`

why it is hitting error:0? which is perhaps division by 0.

Please guide how to get more information on this.

Comment: Can you provide an MCVE?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo how to geet MCVE ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: More detailed question with MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77556886/why-my-example-segfaults-on-movaps-instruction

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions - edit your question instead.